# Files on encrypted LUKS take up more space

Tags: linux, partitioning, encryption, ext4, luks

I have 2 drives (both the same size). One of them just has a simple ext4 partition on it. The other drive is encrypted with LUKS, opened and also formatted with ext4.

However, when I copy files from the unencrypted drive to the encrypted drive, they just take up more space.

For example, a folder on the unencrypted drive is 274G, while the same folder is 342G after I rsynced it to the encrypted drive. That's a 25% increase in size.

What's the cause of this steep increase in size? Is there anyway to alleviate that?

Comment: What are the allocation unit sizes?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the result of `fdisk -l` is `Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes`. It's the same for the unencrypted device and also for the encrypted block device and the /mapper/sdX_crypt

Comment: What are the allocation unit sizes used by the filesystems?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski how do you look up th e allocation unit sizes of an ext4 filesystem?

Comment: These answers for ext3 should work with ext4: [How do I determine the block size of an ext3 partition on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/q/29887)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for the fast reply. The block size is 4096 for both (encrypted/unencrypted) partitions. I formatted both partitions the same way - without specifying a block-size. So I'm guessing that's just the default block size that was picked in both cases

Comment: Maybe use `dumpe2fs` on both partitions redirected to a file each, and inspect (meaning using `diff`) the differences.